# Azure AD SCIM: SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementMultipleEntriesInResponse

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim, scim2

We're using Azure AD as the Identity Provider for User Provisioning into our system.
We have started getting this error of late.

```
EntrySynchronizationError
Result      Failure
Description Failed to match an entry in the source and target systems User 'XXX@XXX.com'
ErrorCode   SystemForCrossDomainIdentityManagementMultipleEntriesInResponse
```

There has been no change in our scim server code. The error message is obviously stating it's fetching more than 1 entry when it should return 1 but in reality, there is no user with the said username & Azure AD should be sending a request to create a new one.
This is happening under the action "Other", I'm guessing it's a GET.
Any idea on what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

A GET operation with a filter (ie: GET /Users?filter=userName eq "Test_User_dfeef4c5-5681-4387-b016-bdf221e82081") is expecting either 0 or 1 result to be returned, but is receiving more than one result. Either your configuration in provisioning is matching on an attribute that is not uniqueness constrained (ie: department eq "Sales") or there's a problem with your logic for returning filtered results.